# Fingerprint scanner with off-device matching

Tags: fingerprint-scanner

For a custom attendance system we're looking for a fingerprint scanner module with an SDK, that can be used in a scenario where initial registration is done at the central office. Workers have no dedicated sites, so they can show up basically at random at any site, where they have to be identified by their fingerprint only. The system should be able to handle 10k+ fingerprints at the same time.

If I'm correct we need a central database of workers that contains hashes of the fingerprints (or the raw data, but we want to avoid that scenario). We want to minimize the time spent on the "matching algorithm". To make that possible the scanner should be able to provide the hash. That way we only need to compare two strings to match workers. We don't need a forensic grade product, so it is no problem if sometimes fails to identify someone, although it shouldn't do any mismatches. This fingerprint module will be embedded to our device.

Does anybody have such experience with scanners?
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Do you have a budget for this?

Comment: The price of all hardware will be paid by our client, so we don't have a target budget. However we want to know how much it will cost. One of the main reason of this question is to be able to estimate the cost of the fingerprint module.

Comment: I think you should read this. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43587/is-iphones-fingerprint-signature-a-one-way-hash